# Is having a master script handle smaller scripts a violation of SRP / high cohesion in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, module, single-responsibility-principle

I created multiple small scripts to follow a modular pattern in Unity. However, this scripts may need information from other scripts. I am doing this so I can reuse the scripts as components for other objects. Is creating a "master" script that group these scripts bad practice or a violation of SRP? Is there a better way of approaching this that I should look into? Events maybe?

Let's say that I have an Enemy, and when that enemy dies, it will drop some loot and give some experience. I created a script for Experience, Loot, Death, and Health. Each will hold a couple of functions. I created a "master" script, called EnemyHandler, and this script decides when to launch each script. The methods get activated from a Health event whenever the enemy gets damaged, and EnemyHandler is a subscriber of that event.

Another options was to use an OnHealthChanged event and an extra OnDeath event and trigger each script, but I feel that will make them more dependent.

This is my code (each class is a different script)

```
class AnimalHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IHealth ihealth;

    [SerializeField]
    private ObjectDeath objectDeath;

    [SerializeField]
    private SmokeEffect smokeEffect;

    [SerializeField]
    private LootSpawner lootSpawner;

    [SerializeField]
    private ExperienceAdder experienceAdder;

    [SerializeField]
    private animalRange animalRangeScript;

    void Start()
    {
        ihealth = gameObject.GetComponent<IHealth>();
        ihealth.OnHealthChanged += WhenAnimalDies;    
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        ihealth.OnHealthChanged -= WhenAnimalDies;        
    }

    public void WhenAnimalDies(float healthPercentage)
    {
        if (healthPercentage <= 0f)
        {
            objectDeath.Dead();
            smokeEffect.ProduceSmoke();
            lootSpawner.SpawnLoot();
            experienceAdder.AddExperience();
        }
    }
}

class SmokeEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject smoke;

    public void ProduceSmoke()
    {
        Instantiate(smoke, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
}

class LootSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Lootbag when the animal dies
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject lootbag;

    public void SpawnLoot()
    {
        lootbag.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        lootbag.transform.position = transform.position;
    }
}

class Health : MonoBehaviour, IHealth
{
    [SerializeField]
    private int maxHealth;
    private int currentHealth;
    public int CurrentHealth{..}

    public float CurrentHealthPercentage
    {
        get { return (float)CurrentHealth / (float)maxHealth; }
    }

    public event Action<float> OnHealthChanged = delegate { };

    void Start()
    {
        CurrentHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    public void ChangeHealth(int healthChange)
    {
        if (CurrentHealth <= 0)
            return;

        CurrentHealth += healthChange; //Damage is a negative number
        OnHealthChanged(CurrentHealthPercentage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Does this violate SRP? No

SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) states that a class should manage itself. In the case of your code, your classes **are** managing themselves. When an enemy dies, it has effects: smoke, animation, loot drop, experience and so on. As such, the classes that handle...those effects are passed into your enemy class and when the enemy dies, it says "oh, dead now, hey post-dead-stuff, do your thing."

If this violated the SRP then no class ever would be able to invoke methods on any other class ever. Your enemy's *responsibility* is to spawn loot. It doesn't know what kind, how it happens, or any other detail, just that it knows it has a loot object and that on death its responsibility is to call `loot.spawn()`.

Comment: Do you think this is the best way of managing the modular classes?, or would you use an event system without a "master class" that handles all the modular classes.

Comment: "Best" how? As for an event system, no, I would not use an event system for this. You might still *want* an event system that still broadcasts that the enemy died, but I would not use it for loot drops.

Answer (score 0):

It is known as a God Object

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object

I would recommend not to do this because that object knows too much and instead I would recommend Dependency Injection (DI)

(Also if you use that God Object as a Singleton you will have it everywhere in your application, imagine you want to rename it and you have no IDE help, you will have to go to every single file and do it, that is high cohesion)

https://www.codementor.io/mrfojo/c-with-dependency-injection-k2qfxbb8q

Comment: The example here is not a god object. A god object knows about everything: every enemy, every loot object, every powerup, every condition, *everything.* An enemy knowing about (or having a reference to) its own loot items is pretty contained.